# Docker - Rstudio - R old version running together

Tags: r, hyperlink, docker, containers, rstudio

I'm working with docker since approximately a week and I don't understand some of the linking containers stuff.

I've downloaded from rocker, the latest images of Rstudio. It work nicely, everything is ok. I have one own made container with an old R version (let's say humm 3.1.0-1 for example). What I want to do is to use Rstudio from rocker with my own made R version. But this is where I don't understand. How it works ? Is it possible ? If I can do that that'll be awesome but I really don't understand how.

If someone have a solution, that'll be really great.

This is my dockerfile for my old R version :

```
#Get trusty version of ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:trusty

#We need to have https for cran
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install apt-transport-https

#We add the mirror directory to get older version packages
RUN echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

#We clean and get authentication key
RUN apt-get clean && gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E084DAB9

#We add the key
RUN gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | apt-key add -

#We now update our lib
RUN apt-get -y update

# --> R PACKAGE INSTALLATION <--

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install r-base-core=3.1.0-1trusty0
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y --force-yes install r-doc-html=3.1.0-1trusty0
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install r-base-dev=3.1.0-1trusty0

#Check version

RUN R --version
```

I used : docker build -t r-basev3-1-0-1 .  to build it and that works fine. It's just the link between rstudio and my container that I can't figure it out how to do it.

Thank's in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible (or easy) to link RStudio in one container to R in another container, as containers are supposed to be isolated from each other. The easiest thing to do is probably to build your own `r-base` image by modifying this file https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/master/r-base/Dockerfile (just need to change the version part I think) and then build your own rstudio image based on this customized image by modifying files in this folder https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/tree/master/rstudio (change the `FROM` part to your own customized image).

Comment: I though about that but they get unstable version in their code :/ I'll modify it till it works haha ... Maybe with docker compose ? If something can allow me to don't modify all the official code that'll be great :)